# Salt length in SHA-512 version of Unix crypt command

Tags: encryption, sha-256, password-hashing, salt, sha-512

[SHA-512 crypt specs](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) reports that SHA-512 crypt uses 128bit salt.

The [FreeBSD/Linux password generation code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libpam/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix.c#L472) builds the salt using 16 bytes random data (128bits) and then it translates the random data using something like the [B64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#B64) (which is a base64 variation).

An advisor is reporting that:

> because of the cardinality of the subset, each character represents 6 bits of information. Having a salt of size 16 characters generated by this method gives 16x6 = 96 bits of pseudo random data.

In conclusion it looks like the salt of this implementation uses only 96 bits.

I don't agree with this because here the B64 is just used to have printable characters.
The random values are used to pick up a valid character.
Base64 encoded string grows in length, here we have the same length.
The random string is then used as it is by the SHA-512 implementation (where it pass a 128 bit value).

Can somebody confirm the advisor statement and explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis of the [C code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libpam/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix.c#L472) is off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It outputs a string of [`SALTSIZE`=32](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libpam/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix.c#L74) characters each obtained by indexing a string of 64 base-characters encoded in ASCII as a single byte. The indexes are obtained according to the low-order $4\times6$ bits of what seems to a pseudo-random 32-bit value produced by `arc4random()`.

Thus the output is a 32-byte bytestring (not counting the string terminator character/byte) with each byte drawn from a set of 64, thus $32\times8=256\,$bits, with $32\,\log_2(64)=192\,$bits of entropy (at most, assuming full-entropy source).

I conclude neither "16x6 = 96 bits of pseudo random data" nor "128 bit value" apply to what the linked code produces. But wait, the linked [specification](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) tells

> For the SHA-based methods the SALT string can be a simple string of which up to 16 characters are used.

which suggests that something (at least, the code that does cryptography with the salt) should truncate that 32-character salt to 16. In which case there remains a 16-byte bytestring with each byte drawn from a set of 64, thus $16\times8=128\,$bits, with $16\,\log_2(64)=96\,$bits of entropy (at most, assuming full-entropy source).

That matches what the advisor states, although the end could be restated more clearly with "gives 16x6 = 96 bits *worth* of pseudo random data".

The statement "Base64 encoded string grows in length" applies to Base64 encoding, not to what the code does.

---

Addition per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/188805):

> Should this be formally a 128 bit salt or a 96 bit salt?

My (debatable) position: after truncation to 16 characters, the salt is 128-bit with $2^{96}$ possible values, thus to be considered (at best) as effective as a 96-bit uniformly random salt with full entropy from the standpoint of preventing pre-computations. Which is way enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libcrypt/crypt-sha512.c#L97]) salt is truncated to 16 chars.
So at the end we have a 128 bit long salt generated from a 96 bits of entropy.

Should this be formally a 128 bit salt or a 96 bit salt?

Comment: @JohnP: see updated answer. Notice that on second though, I think that what the advisor states ought to be clarified by strategically adding _"worth"_.